# Why is 'font-family' not inherited in '<button>' tags automatically?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have noticed that in case of `<button>` tags, **font-family** is not inherited automatically; either I must specify it explicitly like:

```
<button style="font-family: some_style;">Button</button>
```

or use **inherit** property like this:

```
<button style="font-family: inherit;">Button</button>
```

However, the *font-family* is automatically inherited in case of other tags, the `<a>` tag for example.

Why do we have this issue with the `<button>` tags?

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/svkq54L9/)**.

Comment: Because the elements are rendered differently by each user-agent (browser) who have their own specific stylings. There is no agreed upon button `element` that is "standard" cross-browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are CSS-styles not inherited by HTML form fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250259/why-are-css-styles-not-inherited-by-html-form-fields)

Comment: what's even worse is that when I look in the Inspector it *claims* that the font-family has been inherited, but the actual font displayed doesn't match what it claims it should be!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Form elements don't inherit font settings, you have to set these properties manually.

If you use font declaration for eg. body,

```
body {font-family: arial, sans-serif}
```

use just

```
body, input, textarea, button {font-family: arial, sans-serif}
```

or

```
input, textarea, button {font-family: inherit}
```

Comment: Haha, I don't think that will even target his `<button>` element.

Comment: But, *why* don't they inherit font settings?
Why was this a CSS design choice? ... (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻

Comment: another obnoxious design choice by implementors of the lacking spec

Answer (score 9):

If you inspect your demo in a browser using its Developer Tools, you can see that the font family of the `button` element comes from the *browser style sheet*. They show this in different ways, and they may use different fonts there, but the principle is the same: there is a declaration for the `font-family` property of the element in *some* style sheet, hence that property cannot be inherited (unless you explicitly set the value `inherit` on it, of course).

This is not defined in specifications, but neither are such browser style sheet settings prohibited by them, and they are common practice.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, and I am answering late. Both @panther and @jukka-k-korpela answer the question correctly. However, they are missing one key information about the fix for the precise question and the demo provided by @nikunj-madhogaria. I attempt to complete the answer according to the question.

Since the question is about the `button` tag, it is probably wise to add `button` to the CSS fix provided by @panther. So, here is the correct fix for the button tag:

```
button { font-family: inherit }
```

Answer (score 3):

Old reply but it might help some people. I added the following:

```
* {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif
}
```