# CSS - Text link larger than buttons

Tags: css

I have a style for inputs on my page, with some basic padding and font size, I tried applying the same style to a link, but for some reason the link is always larger (height) than the button no matter what I do, even with the exact same text and font size, I tried doing `display: block` but that just makes the button the width of the screen.

Here is the CSS:

```css
.button{
  padding: 10px 15px 7px 15px!important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-3{
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  border: 1px solid #ff4d4d !important;
}
```

I've looked at the Chrome styles panel and confirmed the font / padding is being used (it's not strikken through).

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the `line-height`?

Comment: Try setting `border: none;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this kind of stuff I always set the font family I used.

Take a look at this example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/tnr0jxka/

You also might want to consider adding:-webkit-apperance:none;-moz-apperance:none; to this kind of css, it will save you big time in cross-browser experience.

Comment: Setting the font family in the button itself seemed to do the trick, even through it was supposed to be inheriting from the body on both it wasn't working correctly, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the issue is because:

- You aren't using a CSS reset.
- The `line-height` needs to be the same.

Make sure you give a consistent `line-height` to both. For now, set in the both:

```
line-height: 1.5;
```

This should fix it. Also, you can compare both the styles with the computed ones, to check if there's anything else being set. Since you say `<button>`, it might also have some `border`.

Also, like I guessed, you are also giving `border` and same colour as background to the button, making it look `2px` bigger.

When you open the Developer Tools, try comparing the **Computed Styles** part:

[image: comp styles]

Comment: I checked and the border is being applied to both equally,also, line height seems to only affect the input button even though its in the class for both of them.

Comment: @Mankind1023 Obviously the main thing you would have noticed would be the `font-family`, which I forgot to mention. Anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons do not inherit the global styling automatically.
So, setting font-size of button explicitly will solve the problem

[see this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140050/why-is-font-family-not-inherited-in-button-tags-automatically/26140154#:%7E:text=Because%20the%20elements%20are%20rendered,%22standard%22%20cross%2Dbrowser.) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same issue and I had set all my line-heights and other stuff as told, didnt help. However I found out they were differt display properties, so setting both to (display: 'inline-block') solved the issue.