# Trouble making <a> anchor tags and <button> elements exactly the same

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble making side by side `<a>` and `<button>` appear identical.

Here is a minimum example that shows the issue

```css
html, body {
  font-family: 'canada-type-gibson';
  font-size: 10px;
}

.size1 {
  /* we are using base font-size here */
}
.link1 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.button1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: none;
  background:none;
  border:none;
}

.size2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.link2 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.button2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: none;
  background:none;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="size1">
      <a class="link1">LINK</a>
      <button class="button1">BUTTON</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="size2">
      <a class="link2">LINK</a>
      <button class="button2">BUTTON</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? I have no problem (for me) deleting this question, but I believe the keywords in it are useful for future searching. This topic does not arise in searching by these keywords. It is only obvious if you recall that font-family is not inherited in form elements.

Answer (score 0):

just change your font size to match each other.

```
.size1 {  font-size: 20px;}

.size2 {  font-size: 20px;}
```

Comment: My usage of font-size `10` and `20` were very intentional to show the non-proportionate differences between the two elements and also the font-weight difference.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it while making this question. I would like to share the answer rather than delete the question, so that others can find it later.

The issue seems to be that `font-family` is not inherited, so it needs to be explicitly defined.

See: [Why is 'font-family' not inherited in '<button>' tags automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140050/why-is-font-family-not-inherited-in-button-tags-automatically)

```css
html, body {
  font-family: 'canada-type-gibson';
  font-size: 10px;
}

.link1 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.button1 {
  font-family: 'canada-type-gibson';
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: none;
  background:none;
  border:none;
}

.link2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.button2 {
  font-family: 'canada-type-gibson';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: none;
  background:none;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a class="link1">LINK</a>
      <button class="button1">BUTTON</button>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <a class="link2">LINK</a>
      <button class="button2">BUTTON</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My final solution was to simply put the `font-family` style on all `button` elements at the root level:

```
button {
  font-family: 'canada-type-gibson';
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

`<button>` font-size must also be explicitly declared as it is not inherited from parent elements.

> Removing default button style

I did not talk about in the question or answer, but to make a button look like an `<a>` tag, these styles are desired on the `<button>` in order to remove the default gray appearance:

```
outline: none;
background:none;
border:none;
```

Comment: They are by default the same Font.,

Comment: No they aren't. Run the example.

Comment: i did yes they are Exactly the same just one is larger

Comment: Which is the problem. I wanted them to be identical.

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140050/why-is-font-family-not-inherited-in-button-tags-automatically