# Global font-family not applying to button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I create a button and a link component in the following way using styled-components

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const style = css`

    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:2rem;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:var(--white);
    background-color:transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:1.25rem 3rem;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:.15rem; 
    
    &:hover,
    &:active {
        color:var(--colorFour);
    }

`

export const StyledButton = styled.button`${style}`
export const StyledLink = styled(Link)`${style}`
```

I also have a global style in my project, that sets a global font-family

```
body {
  font-family: 'Comic Neue', sans-serif;
  height:100vh;
  padding:0 2rem;

  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background: var(---colorOne);  
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--colorTwo), var(--colorOne));
}
```

When I use the link component, the correct style `'Comic Neue'` is applied

However, if I use the button the styled applied is for some reason `-apple-system`

The weird thing is, that when I look in the calculated styles for the button, it looks like the `'Comic Neue'` should apply, but for some reason it doesn't

[image]

Anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Form elements fo not inherit the `font-family` property.

Add a `font-family: inherit` CSS property to the button to use the same font as the body.

```
button {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

Comment: The `font-family` is Inherited by default.

Comment: not in forms https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140050/why-is-font-family-not-inherited-in-button-tags-automatically