# Inherited font-size property pushing button from the top of the web page

Tags: html, css, web, inheritance, font-size

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      body {
        font-size: 60px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Just why</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have this code and my problem is that I don't understand why does the inherited font-size from body behave like this on my button element.

I would expect that font-size will change font-size same as it would if I set this property directly to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following ruleset between the  tags. It will force your button to inherit your body's font-size:

```
button {
font-size: inherit;
}
```

Comment: This is not the solution I am looking for. I am trying to resolve, why it happens.

Comment: I think this previous discussion could be helpful then: [Why is 'font-family' not inherited in '<button>' tags automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140050/why-is-font-family-not-inherited-in-button-tags-automatically).

Comment: Thank you, I learned some information from that thread, but this is still mystery. Why font-size is pushing element from the top?