# Why text inside <select> / <option> list is not affected by CSS applied to parent <html> element?

Tags: html, css

Why text inside `<select>` / `<option>` list is not affected (color of "item1", "item2" is not changed) by CSS applied to parent `<html>` element? All `<p>` elements are affected!

Also, this works: `<select multiple style="color:red;">`

```css
:root {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p> this text is affected

<!-- but item1, item2, etc within this list are not affected! -->
<select multiple>
  <optgroup label=animals>
    <option value="it1"> item1 </option>
    <option vslue="it3"> item2 </option>
    <option> item3 </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label=tiran>
    <option> item4 </option>
    <option selected> item5 </option>
    <option> </option>
    <optgroup>
</select>
```

When else same things happen and what rule shall I know about this problem?

I thought that CSS is inherited by child elements.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612302/which-css-properties-are-inherited) means that `color:` CSS property shall be inherited.

P.S. **It seems that `<select>` is considered to be a form element and *form elements do not inherit* any properties (for example, from such parent as `<body>` or `<html>`) - according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250259/why-are-css-styles-not-inherited-by-html-form-fields), same would also apply to `<input>`, `<button>` and `<textarea>`**

Answer (score 0):

CSS elements only inherit values for a property when they have a rule that tells them to. e.g.

```
color: inherit;
```

… or when the property is inherited by default and no other rule overrides it.

The default rules for any given element are set by the [browser's built-in stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements).

These are added to by stylesheets from website authors and users.

Comment: in my example if I have <p> text inside <body> then text is red meaning that at least <p> inherited (?), even indirectly: <html> -> <body> -> <p>

Comment: @user10777718 — What's your point? I said "The default rules for any given element are set by the browser's built-in stylesheet.". Browsers set different rules for different elements.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something but color of text inside <p> tag cannot be red by browser default. Also, default Chrome CSS has nothing like color: inherit for <p> - at least in this spec: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css (taken from your link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements)

Comment: Also this SO answer means that color CSS property shall be inherited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612302/which-css-properties-are-inherited

Comment: If it was inherited in all circumstances then links would not be blue by default. https://i.imgur.com/yUkL2Po.png

Comment: The inherited column in the table you link to only refers to elements which don't have a value specified in a stylesheet (including the browser vendor stylesheet). https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#inheritance

Answer (score -1):

You can't in general. These elements are OS-dependent and are not part of the HTML/browser. It cannot be styled via CSS.
You can find some libraries on internet but, it is composed of HTML elements like div that can be styled.

Comment: As the question points out, setting the `color` on the `<select>` element directly works. So it isn't true that you can't style it.